# Creating the Lucene Analyzer object

Tags: java, netbeans, lucene

I am trying my hands on the apache Lucene IBM tutorials 
 on the following link
 http://www.irsi.res.in/winter-school/slides/LuceneTutorial_IRSI_WinterSchool_2010_v1.0.pdf

I have imported both the lucene 3.6.2 and 4.1.0 libraries in the NetBeans IDE
 for the tutorials but both give the same complain.

but when I try to create an object of the Analyzer , NetBeans 
 complains that it is not a suitable constructor StandardAnalyzer();.

Below are the relevant imports

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
```

Below is the code

```
  Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

What version you are using for Lucene?
Check this latest documentation at http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html

With StandardAnalyzer you have to provide version details also

Comment: both lucene 4.1.0 and 3.6.2 give the same complain

Comment: Yes because there is no such constructor in StandardAnalyzer class. Check the java docs as shared earlier

Answer (score 0):

there are several versions of Lucene 
 the get the version for the StandardAnalyzer object 
 I used the

```
Version.your_Version
```

so for example

```
StandardAnalyzer sa = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.36);
```

for the 3.6.x version of lucene